# Regex non greedy match with tab character

Tags: regex, vi

I do not understand why if given the following line (vi with set list on)

```
10.0.6.5^IVirtual^IVmware^IHTTP, MS SQL, Windows SVC^IcpHelpdesk $
```

Why the following regex:

```
^I.*?^I
```

does not match the string 'Virtual' in my line above? I am using the regex below in my VI search and replace

```
:%s/^I.*?^I/replace/g
```

this returns no match however on the same string if I use

```
^I.*^I
```

I would get

```
10.0.6.5replaceIcpHelpdesk $
```

What I attempting to say with `^I.*?^I` is from the first tab character (`^I`) match anything (with the dot except line breaks) zero or more times ( `*?` ) until you come to the next token with is the tab character (`^I`)

I don't see what I am missing and any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: In most regex languages `^` means the start of the string and `\t` would be a tab character.

Comment: What program are you using again as regex engine?

Comment: Is the example a multiline string, or doe it have literal `^`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about vim regex here? In that case the non-greedy quantifier is `\{-}`:

```
\t.\{-}\t
```

Otherwise you can do it by not matching tab characters with a negation group:

```
\t[^\t]*\t
```

Comment: Thor - Thank you very much I was referring to vim regex and did not know there was a different non-greedy quantifier. Time to do some reading on my end. Thanks again

Comment: If you're familiar with Python's regex system (which is not all that different from Perl's), it should not be hard to wrap your head around vim's regexp-system. http://vimregex.com/ is a good place to start. For any symbols that you don't recognize subsequently, searching for them in vim's native help files should fill in most of the remaining gaps. For me, it was the non-matching group symbol that they didn't explain, so I did ```h: \%(``` and got my answer